# php email going to the 'from' address not the to address

Tags: php, forms, email

I have been searching for a working email php script, I have everything working except -

The email that is entered into the contact form receives the message instead of the pre-set recipient?

I have tried all sorts of tricks to try and get this to work, the only way I can get the mail to arrive in my web-mail account is if I type that address into the form as the senders email.

This is the 'html' form

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="new-mail.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
  <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the php mailer -

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email = 'net@webmail.address';
$who_sent = $_POST['contact'];
$headers = 'From: ' . $who_sent . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $who_sent . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$name = $_POST['name'];

mail($email, $subject, $message, $name, $headers);
?>
```

When the mail is received at the intended senders email address it list's the recipient as being the intended send to address, and the from address is the web host 'user@server.web-host.net'

I am finding this a little confusing, I have tried setting the form id and name for the email field to different text, I have tried putting the recipients address directly into the mail(), and a good many other combinations too. For some reason it makes no difference to the outcome.

The host is 000webhost.com which is a linux based server if that makes any difference to this.

Comment: What happens when you directly call the `mail()` function with literal values, not from a form, with a simple address, subject and message?

Comment: mail($email, $subject, $message, $name, $headers); <- $name is where $headers should be.

Comment: `mail($email, $subject, $message,$headers)` is the proper mail function

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php as @OIS pointed out. Your paramaters are wrong.

Comment: I spent a few hours experimenting based on your comments and this is my final mail function <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$text = $_POST['message'];
$contact = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$message = "From: " . $name . "<br/><br/>" . "Messae : <br/>" .$text;

$headers = 'From: $contact' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: $contact' . "\r\n" . "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$mailto = 'net@weedy101.netii.net';

mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers );
?>